# Android PubNub not receiving push notification via FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I made an app which uses PubNub (version 4.x.x) && FCM.

Server sends me a JSON according the following format:

```
{
    "pn_apns": {
        "aps": {
            "alert": "This is a push notification",
            "badge": 9,
            "sound": "bingbong.aiff",
            "payload": {
                "title": "Beastiality",
                "message": "xxxx"
            },
            "type": 1
        }
    },
    "pn_gcm": {
        "data": {
            "title": "Beastiality",
            "message": "xxxxx"
        }
    },
    "content": {
        "title": "Beastiality",
        "message": "xxxxxx"
    }
}
```

The `pn_gcm` is indicated, but I don't receive any push. If I make a push from Firebase console, it works fine. Is it a known issue or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I receive the subscribe from pubnub callback, but dont receive the push notification

Comment: I consolidated my comments into an answer. Please review and comment if still having issues or accept as answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Subscribe for Realtime Messages vs. Register for Push Notifications

Subscribe and push notifications (GCM and APNS) are not directly related in PubNub. You have to register for push notifications on channels and has nothing to do with the subscribe method.

**Instructions:**

- Follow [PubNub docs to setup/config GCM](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4).
- Make sure the [device is registered for GCM push notifications](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/1127/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues)
- Troubleshoot using [PubNub mobile push troubleshooting guide](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/1127/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues)